# Написание структуры контейнера set

Tags: c++

Написать структуру, которая обрабатывала бы входные данные следующим образом.
На входе даётся целое число, указывающее количество операций. Затем сами операции:

операция добавление элемента в контейнер и сам элемент: ADD  5;

операция проверки наличие элемента и вывод в консоль "YES", если элемент есть и "NO", если элемент не найден: PRESENT 3;

вывод в консоль общее количество элементов конетейнера: COUNT.

Например:
На входе:

4

ADD 5

PRESENT 3

PRESENT 5

COUNT

Ответ:

NO

YES

1

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>    
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct SET{
    set<int>s;
    int add_num(int n){cin>>n; return s.insert(n);} 
    void present_num(int n);
    void COUNT();
};

void SET::present_num(int n){
    cout << (s.count(n) ? "YES" : "NO") << "\n"; // если количество не 
}                                       //0, тогда "YES", если 0, "NO".

void SET::COUNT(){
    cout << s.size() << endl;
}
int main(){
    int m, n;
    SET s;        
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        string cmd;
        cin >> cmd;
        if(cmd == "ADD") {
            s.add_num(n);
        }
        else if (cmd == "PRESENT"){
            s.present_num(n);
        }
        else if (cmd == "COUNT") s.COUNT();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strncmp` возвращает `0` в случае равенства строк. И советую переписать `void SET::present_num(int n) { cout << (s.count(n) ? "YES" : "NO") << "\n"; }`

Comment: Да, Вы правы, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Непойми что написано. Зачем `int item;`? Почему `char CMD;` а не `std::string CMD;`?

Comment: По моему ваш код не  выполняет задание

Comment: Точно, именно поэтому я и прошу помощи привести его в порядок.

Comment: И если все написано на С++, тогда для чего нужна вообше  функция сравнения С_строк strncmp?

Comment: На курсе нам настоятельно рекомендуют сравнивать именно strncmp, даже не strcmp.

Comment: Это рекомендация  или требование? Если требование, то наверняка  в вашей структуре кроме символного массива ничего не должно быть, а если есть такой контейнер как   std::set, значит  можно написать весь код на языке С++, особенно, что это не будет влиять плохо на быстродействие. И вы должны сравнивать не символ со строкой, а строки

Comment: Нет, не требование.

Comment: Есть один момент на этом сайте: код в вопросе не надо исправлять на правильный. От этого ответы теряют смысл. Откатите, пожалуйста, назад.

Comment: Как это неправильно, гораздо удобнее иметь рабочий код(((, но как скажите, правило, есть правило.

Comment: @Trulimon кстати, можете на мете это обсудить. А вообще, никто не мешает добавить свой ответ с решением после исправлений, не трогая вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Ошибки:

Вы не считываете количество команд. У вас есть цикл, где счетчик сравнивается с переменной `m`, но вы ее не инициализировали. Сделайте это перед входом в цикл, тогда считаете столько команд, сколько требуется.

Вы используете `char` для хранения строки. `char` - это один символ. Вам нужно использовать `string`. Функции `strcmp`, `strncmp` - они работают с типом `char*`. Вы можете конечно его использовать, но это подход более характерный для C, не C++. Будущее уже наступило, `string`и можно сравнивать оператором `==`.

#### Мелкие ошибки:

Вы объявили переменную `n`, передаете в функции, но нигде не пишете в нее. Вместо этого вы читаете из `cin` внутри функции `add_num`. Если вы передаете параметр, вы должны использовать не `cin`, а его. Считывать нужно в мейне, после того как определили команду.

Нет использования переменной `item`. Можно ее убрать.

Вы зачем-то возвращаете `int` из `add_num`, и не используете значение.

#### Почему не правы ваши преподаватели

Вам настоятельно рекомендуют использовать `strncmp`, и я так понял, не объяснили, почему. А разница вот в чем:

`strcmp` - сравнивает строки полностью, поэтому мы и не указываем длину при вызове.
`strncmp` - сравнивает *только первые n символов*.

Это значит, что если вы сравните строки вот так:

```
cout << strncmp ("ADDsgfdghfsdgh", "ADD", 3) << endl;
```

Ответ будет 0, типа строки равны, а на самом деле они не равны.

Comment: Спасибо за исправления. Внёс, как Вы сказали, но код не заработал , к сожалению. Выдаёт следующую ошибку "C:\CPP\ex\untitled\main.cpp:11: ошибка: cannot convert 'std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>, bool>' to 'int' in return
     int add_num(int n){return s.insert(n);}
                                         ^"

Comment: Вызовите просто `s.insert(n)`. Возвращать его не надо, и тип `void` у метода поставьте.

Comment: Удивительно, но код заработал!!!  Спасибо!!! А почему void, ведь мы же изменяем содержимое контейнера?

Comment: @Trulimon void - это лишь возвращаемое значение, которое можно было бы сохранить: `auto i = s.add_num(n);`. Оно не зависит от того, какие у функции побочные эффекты. В нашей ситуации нечего возвращать. Зеленую галочку нажмите пожалуйста.

Comment: Не понял с итератором. Если я вместо функции вставлю auto i = s.add_num(n); откуда он будет знать что нужно вставить элемент в контейнер?

Comment: Метод `insert` это и делает. Вызывая `add_num`, вы вызываете `insert`, который в нем. Он добавляет элемент, а итератор на него вам не нужен.